# Para que serve o Mathf.abs

Tags: c#, unity-5

estou programando no unity e vejo muitas pessoas usando isso, e as vezes ate uso nos meus scripts mas não entendo exatamente oque ele faz "retorna", por favor me explica?

Comment: Valor absoluto (ou módulo) de um número. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Abs.html

Answer (score 0):

Retorna o valor absoluto.

O valor absoluto de um Decimal é seu valor numérico sem seu sinal

como no exemplo na documentação do Unity

```
    Debug.Log(Mathf.Abs(-10.5f));// prints 10.5
    Debug.Log(Mathf.Abs(-10));// prints 10
```